# Converting -10dbm to dbu?

Tags: sound-design, mixing, conversion

I know that -10dbm is supposed to be lesser than 4dbu. But somehow, the [online converter](https://www.qsl.net/pa2ohh/jsdbmdbu.htm) I used to convert dbm to dbu showed the former to be 40dbu, which I believe cannot be the case. So, here's the question.

How to convert the following specs to a definite dbu?

- Rated output level: -10dbm
- Output load impedance:   10kΩ or more

Edit: Adding more information. I am connecting the zoom h1 (with above specs) to a behringer mixer line input, which says impedance: min 4.7kohm.

Comment: Did you get an answer of 40dBu or 40dBuV?

Comment: @Timinycricket 40dBuA & 120dBuV

Comment: the uV stands for microvolts and would mean 40dBuV is -85dBu. I think your specs were supposed to say -10dbV because that is consumer line level. It might be a typo when it says dBm

Comment: Just verified. Looks like zoom alternates between dbv & dbm in many models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert `dbm` to `Watts` using the following:

```
Pw = 10^(Pdbm/10) / 1000

Pw = 10^(-10/10) / 1000 = 0.0001 Watts
```

So the max output power is 0.0001 Watts, and the output load impedance is 10 kOhm. We can now use Ohm's Law to calculate the Voltage:

```
V = I * R
P = I * V
```

which makes

```
V = SQRT(P * R)

V = SQRT(0.0001 * 10000) = 1 Volt
```

now you can go from Volt to dbuV

```
Vdbu = 20log(V/0.775)

Vdbu = 20log(1/0.775) = +2.2 dbuV
```

HTH